# designing Low-Pass Transmission Line Stub Filter

Tags: rf, filter

I'm trying to design a Low-Pass transmission line stub filter, and I have a few question regarding it.

I'm rather new to RF-circuit design, so please bear with me.

If my desired specs include the pass-frequencies and the block-frequencies, does that let me figure out a suitable \$N\$ somehow (does bigger \$N\$ make the slope more steep? How is this determined?)

How do I go about limiting the size of the reflection coefficient, or what counts as \$Z_S\$ in the circuit?

Any useful literature I should dive into in the topic of designing a transmission line stub filter and figuring out the details?

Thanks in advance.

Also, how should I consider the desired attenuation decibel amounts at pass/stop frequencies?

Comment: N is the number of stubs?  All I know about stubs is they act as a lumped inductor or cap.  So use the resulting transfer function.

Comment: I know how to perform the transformations from a basic circuit into stubs, but I'm not sure how to approach the circuitry problem regarding this

Comment: So I've found formulas for Buttersworth's filter where I can decide the cut-off frequency and use that to calculate the component values. I do not know how the order will affect the actual filter's performance, apart from the assumption I made in the OP, or how I can affect the attenuation in pass/stop regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order of your filter (i.e. number of sections) is determined by the stopband attenuation.

You may use the formulae from reference books (1), but I strongly recommend to use free software tools like (2) for that. You'll save a lot of time.

In order to implement a distributed lowpass filter, you should previously design a LC Chebyshev prototype. Then replace inductors by high impedance transmission lines and shunt capacitors by low impedance stubs according to (3):

[image]

[image]

The same procedure applies to lowpass mininum cap. elliptic filters.

[image]

Say, Z0L ~ 20Ohm and Z0H = 400Ohm. YMMV

Hope this helps

[UPDATE]

Example (Chebyshev)
[image]

Example (elliptic)
[image]

(1) Microwave engineering. David M. Pozar. 4th Edition. Section 8.3

(2) http://www.iowahills.com/9RFFiltersPage.html

(3) Microstrip Filters for RF/Microwave Applications. JIA-SHENG HONG. M. J. LANCASTER. JOHN WILEY & SONS, INC. 2001. page 119. Eq. 5.9

Comment: It does, thank you and especially thanks for including a few sources to boot